# How can I change my Minecraft username?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I want to change my Minecraft username, but I cannot find a way to do this anywhere. Is this possible? If so, how can I do so?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply said, this is not possible. [As stated on the official Mojang site:](http://help.mojang.com/customer/portal/articles/928638-minecraft-usernames)

> #### Changing usernames
>
> We do not currently support changing, editing, or correcting usernames, though this may be a feature in the future.
>   Make sure that you choose wisely; it will be used for your multiplayer
>   persona and is visible to others.

However, Mojang is working on a way to make this possible in the future using the new Mojang accounts system. For now though, you can't change it.

Comment: This answer is seriously outdated. At my current point in time (2017) you can change your username every 30 days.

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps. A helpful video tutorial can be found [here](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=M9Zws04m-MI).

1. Migrate your Minecraft account to a Mojang account at accounts.mojang.com/migrate.
2. Log in to your Mojang account.
3. You'll see all the games you play. Next to your Minecraft username you'll see a link to change it.

Hope this helped!